# lib.so missing and no known rule to make it

Tags: android, cmake

From google examples I'm trying to customize hello-libs example addind my shared library libofr_engine_core

but i receive this error...

Error:error: 'C:/Users/.../Downloads/android-ndk-master/hello-libs/distribution/ofr/lib/arm64-v8a/libofr_engine_core.so', needed by 'C:/Users/.../Downloads/android-ndk-master/hello-libs/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libhello-libs.so', missing and no known rule to make it

What I'm doing wrong?

Obviously I have added the .so and .h to my distribution folder

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# configure import libs
set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../distribution)

add_library(lib_gmath STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_gmath PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${distribution_DIR}/gmath/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libgmath.a)

# shared lib will also be tucked into APK and sent to target
# refer to app/build.gradle, jniLibs section for that purpose.
# ${ANDROID_ABI} is handy for our purpose here. Probably this ${ANDROID_ABI} is
# the most valuable thing of this sample, the rest are pretty much normal cmake
add_library(lib_gperf SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_gperf PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${distribution_DIR}/gperf/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libgperf.so)


add_library(libofr_engine_core SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libofr_engine_core PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${distribution_DIR}/ofr/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libofr_engine_core.so)



# build application's shared lib
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

add_library(hello-libs SHARED
            hello-libs.cpp)

target_include_directories(hello-libs PRIVATE
                           ${distribution_DIR}/gmath/include
                           ${distribution_DIR}/gperf/include
                           ${distribution_DIR}/ofr/include
                           )

target_link_libraries(hello-libs
                      android
                      lib_gmath
                      lib_gperf
                      libofr_engine_core
                      log)
```

Comment: The error clearly states that path you set for `libofr_engine_core` library (via *IMPORTED_LOCATION* property) doesn't exist.